# Using Python's LazyLoader to import class import top level module

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-loading, python-importlib

If I do `import os` lazily I can use the method below:

```
os = lazy('os')
```

And it load the library lazily, but if I do:

`path = lazy('os.path')`

The `LazyLoader` is loading the `os` module, then Lazy Loading `path` submodule.  How can I prevent that from happening?

Additionally I do not know if this is supported, but I would like to know if you can do something like this:

```py
from os.path import isdir
```

But have the method be returned in a lazy fashion?

```py
def lazy(fullname):
  if fullname in sys.modules:
    return sys.modules[fullname]
  else:
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    loader = importlib.util.LazyLoader(spec.loader)
    # Make module with proper locking and get it inserted into sys.modules.
    loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```